# Multiplying and Reversing NP Type 'm8[ns]'

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I've been given a function that takes an np.int64 `ts` and transforms it into a datetime object as:
`ts.astype('m8[ns]') * 100 + np.datetime64('0001-01-01T00:00:00')`

What I want to do is make a function that reverses this process --> takes in a datetime object and returns the np.int64.

The thing that is tripping me up is the `* 100` part of the original function, what is it actually doing? Because it's not working as a normal multiply by 100, and if on the reverse step we try to divide by 100 it gives an different answer from the original.

example:

```
ts = np.int64(636903684001437312)

ts.astype('m8[ns]') ==> numpy.timedelta64(636903684001437312,'ns')

ts.astype('m8[ns]')*100 ==> numpy.timedelta64(8350136179015076352,'ns')

numpy.timedelta64(8350136179015076352,'ns')/100 ==> numpy.timedelta64(83501361790150763,'ns')
```

As we see the original `ts.astype('m8[ns]')` gives `636903684001437312`, multiplying by 100 turns it into  a `8350136179015076352` timedelta64 object (why/how?) but dividing that by 100 doesn't give back the original, instead this time it literally divedes it by 100 to give `83501361790150763`.

Comment: if you look at `np.iinfo(np.int64).max` you see that result of multiplication of `ts` by 100  would exceed the maximum integer that can be represented by `np.int64`

Comment: @MrFuppes it is not `ts` which is being multiplied, it's `ts.astype('m8[ns]')` which is `numpy.timedelta64(636903684001437312,'ns')`. What I don't understand is how `numpy.timedelta64(636903684001437312,'ns')` turns into `numpy.timedelta64(8350136179015076352,'ns')` by multiplying the former by 100.

Comment: Check `np.int64(636903684001437312) * 100` - you will get an overflow warning and the result is `8350136179015076352` - it doesn't make a difference if you cast to 'm8[ns]'. Not sure if that is intended in the function you got...